Openstack -Rabitmq cluster issue
We are operating an OpenStack environment managed by Ansible with three controller nodes. Recently, Controller-2 encountered a network partition with RabbitMQ cluster issue that we couldn't resolve, leading us to remove it from the RabbitMQ cluster and do rabbitmqctl reset.
Since then, the RabbitMQ cluster node removal,  We are currently unable to rejoin this node to the RabbitMQ cluster. The following error occurs when attempting to join the cluster:
Controller-2]# rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@ctrl-1-rabbit-mq-container
Clustering node rabbit@ctrl-2 with rabbit@ctrl-1
Error:
{:failed_to_cluster_with, [:"rabbit@ctrl-3", :"rabbit@ctrl-1"], 'Mnesia could not connect to any nodes.'}
We have verified that Controller-2 can communicate with other nodes in the cluster and it responds with a 'pong' for "rabbitmqctl eval 'net_adm:ping('''rabbit@ctrl-1''').'"
There are no additional error logs indicating the root of the problem.
We would appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue.

rabbitmqctl reset on ctrl-2 isn't enough, you also need to issue rabbitmqctl forget_cluster_node rabbit@ctrl-2 from one of the existing cluster members before calling join_cluster operation. But it could be something else as it writes something about Mnesia. Usually, when I'm fixing the RabbitMQ cluster I delete all nodes but one and then create new ones. You just need to ensure, that your first node (e.g. rabbitmq@ctrl-1) is OK, check vhosts (rabbitmqctl list_vhosts), permissions (rabbitmqctl list_permissions), almost every OpenStack component needs its own vhost, user and proper permissions... You wrote that you use Ansible... You probably mean Kolla-Ansible or Openstack-Ansible, right? I don't know them much, but there is a chance that they include some playbook or tasks for fixing the cluster automatically, did you check this?

I had the cluster forget form other node . So currently the two are in cluster and see them ok and  all vhosts for the open stack component.  We don't rebuild the container and  was trying to get fixed on the same. Verified all task and playbook but not seen any. One option was recreating the container but we didn't want to do  the same as  not sure if any other issue causing this behavior.
